# What are some of the greatest predictions of new phenomena in condensed matter theory?

Tags: solid-state-physics

In condensed matter, most theories were developed to understand experimental results that could not be understood using classical physics or the contemporaneous theory. One can think for example of black body radiation, photoelectric effects or superconductivity. But aside from its explanatory power, has condensed matter theories ever predicted a new phenomena? What are some good examples?

If you look at the edits to this question, it was originally about predictions by many-body field theory (low energy) but I decided instead to convert it into a condensed matter one as I got no reactions, however any examples in this domain are also welcome.

Answer (score 2):

I think [topological insulators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_insulator) and the [Josephson effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Josephson_effect) would be good examples.

The [theoretical roots](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_insulator#Prediction) of **topological insulators** go back to the 1980s, but [Kane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charles_L._Kane) and [Mele](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eugene_J._Mele)'s 2005 theory paper on ["$Z_2$ topological order and the quantum spin Hall effect"](https://arxiv.org/abs/cond-mat/0506581) is usually given the most credit for their theoretical discovery. In 2006 [Bernevig](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B._Andrei_Bernevig), Hughes, and [Zhang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shoucheng_Zhang) made a [specific theoretical prediction](https://arxiv.org/abs/cond-mat/0611399) that quantum spin Hall insulator states could be realized in HgTe quantum wells, and this was [experimentally observed in 2007](https://arxiv.org/abs/0710.0582) by the [Molenkamp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laurens_W._Molenkamp) lab.

The **Josephson Effect** was [predicted](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Josephson_effect#History)  by [Brian Josephson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brian_Josephson) in 1962, and [experimentally observed](https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevLett.10.230) in 1963 by [Phil Anderson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Philip_W._Anderson) and John Rowell.